# ECDSA signature size too long?

Tags: c++, crypto++

I'm creating a key pair using

```
ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::Signer signer;
signer.AccessKey().Initialize(randomGeneratorM, ASN1::secp160r1());
...
ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::PublicKey publicKey;
signer.AccessKey().MakePublicKey(publicKey);
```

Loading, saving, signing and verification works fine. But my signature is always 42 bytes, when I expected it to be "40" (twice the size of the 160 key bits).

The signature is generated as:

```
std::string data ...
ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::Signer signer(privateKey);
byte signatureBuffer[42];
size_t signatureLength = signer.SignMessage(
  randomGeneratorM, (const byte*)data.c_str(), data.size(), signatureBuffer);
```

I couldn't find any documentation that the signature might be encoded. So I'm curious: where do the extra bytes come from?

In fact, `signer.MaxSignatureLength()` returns "42" and for all the signatures generated so far, the signature length was never anything other.

I am aware that "42" is the answer to life, the universe and everything ;)

Oh, and CryptoPP V5.6.2, Visual Studio 2008 
Sample signature (in hex):

> 00F9C6853895481DDA23517DE16AA44518CDB2C9A900FF9AACA718DFB2AAA9C10E45265224EC40C7FD63

Comment: It's ASN.1 encoded, which should account for the two bytes of overhead

Comment: I think it should just be '10 28' (in hex)

Comment: @Petesh: I thought of that too, because it's used for the keys, too. But when I feed the signature to dumpasn1 it tells me "inconsistent length" and "further data to follow", so it must be something different.

Comment: @Petesh: It's not ASN.1 encoded. It's just two raw 21-byte integers concatenated. The integers are signed (this requirement does come from ASN.1), so a leading 00 byte is necessary if the top bit is set (as it is for both integers here). Probably CryptoPP inserts this 00 byte anyway, otherwise I don't see how the thing could be reliably decoded. IMHO, such a 'stripped' signature should always be 40 bytes, but nobody listens to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I couldn't find any documentation that the signature might be encoded. So I'm curious: where do the extra bytes come from?

Crypto++ uses IEEE P1363 encoding of the `{R,S}` tuple, which is a simple concatenation. The 42 is `MaxImage()` size, which is the largest the signature can be. That's based on the encoding of the `{R,S}` tuple under the P1363 standard.

If interested, digital signature formats are discussed at [Cryptographic Interoperability: Digital Signatures](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25590/Cryptographic-Interoperability-Digital-Signatures).

---

> 00F9C6853895481DDA23517DE16AA44518CDB2C9A900FF9AACA718DFB2AAA9C10E45265224EC40C7FD63

This breaks out to:

```
00F9C6853895481DDA23517DE16AA44518CDB2C9A9
00FF9AACA718DFB2AAA9C10E45265224EC40C7FD63
```

which is a concatenation of two ASN.1 encoded values *without* the integer type information. Crypto++ knows the size of `R` and `S` because its an integral part of the domain parameters. Specifically, its `ASN1::secp160r1()` which is a 160-bit curves.

ASN.1 Integers are two's compliment encoded (see ITU's X.690 [Specification of Basic Encoding Rules (BER), Canonical Encoding Rules (CER) and Distinguished Encoding Rules (DER)](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.690-200811-I/en) and friends), and `R` and `S` are positive per IEEE P1363 (see IEEE's P1363 Section 5.6.1 [Converting Between Integers and Bit Strings](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/1363/IBC/material/P1363.3-D1-200805.pdf)). So you have to have a leading `0x00` octet.

If you used `secp256r1()`, then `MaxImage()` and `MaxSignatureLength()` would increase accordingly.

---

For completeness, Java using a different form of encoding. Here it is:

```
SEQUENCE ::= {
  r INTEGER,
  s INTEGER
}
```

That means you have a 20 octets `r` plus 2 octets for ASN.1 integer encoding, 20 octets `s` plus 2 octets for ASN.1 integer encoding, and 2 octets for the sequence encoding. For a total of 46 octets. If `r` or `s` is negative in 2's compliment format, then you need to add a byte for the leading 0x00 octet. So it could be 48 bytes.

---

Crypto++ offers a function for converting between P1363, Java and OpenPGP signatures called `DSAConvertSignatureFormat`. You can see the source code in [dsa.cpp](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/dsa_8cpp_source.html) (there's not much to it).

Answer (score 0):

A signature consists of an {R,S} tuple. Due to the specification of how to create the signature:

- R will always be lower than both, the field base prime 'p' as well as the base point order 'r'
- S will be lower than the base point order 'r', which may be higher than the field base prime 'p'

For most curves, the base point order 'r' is less than the prime 'p'. This is not the case for curve secp160r1. For secp160r1, the prime 'p' has 160 bits, while the base point order 'r' has 161 bits.

161 bits will not fit into 20 bytes, so 21 bytes must be used for S. And P1363 specifies that R shall be encoded on the same number of bytes as S.

More specifically, IEEE Std 1363(TM):2000 specifies that the output of ECDSA is R concatenated with S, where each is a network-order byte-string with a length equal to the byte-length of the order of the generator.